# Solving a strange type of equation, expressed in terms of scalar products.

Tags: functions, products

I'm trying to solve the equation
$$
-f(a+b,c,d)e^{a\cdot b}+f(a,b+c,d)e^{b\cdot c}-f(a,b,c+d)e^{c\cdot d}-f(a+d,b,c)e^{-a\cdot d}=0,
$$
with $a,b\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and the scalar product $a\cdot b=a_1b_2-a_2b_1$. The function f is assumed to be Taylor expandable in the scalar procucts of its arguments. Moreover, since the vectors $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}^2$, we have
$$
(a\cdot b)(c\cdot d)+(b\cdot c)(a\cdot d)-(a\cdot c)(b\cdot d)=0.
$$
This identity follows from the fact that in $\mathbb{R}^2$ no more than 2 vectors can be linearly independent.

So the question is simply how to solve this. I don't need a full answer, but it would be nice have a general direction to look into, cause I'm kind of in the dark what methods to use.

Thanks in advance!

-Edit: I'm trying to solve for the function $f$, given any vectors $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}^2$. I've already tried Taylor expanding, hoping to get some set of differential equations and I'm currently trying to work out some power expansion of $f$ to see if I can find some recursive formula for the coefficients.

Comment: Are you looking for $a,b,c,d$ which satisfy this for a certain fixed $f$ or vice versa?

Comment: I'm looking for a function f which satisfies this for any $a, b, c, d$.

Comment: It could help if you provided some context, e.g. where did you encounter such equation?

Comment: That's part of my problem too. It's just a random problem without any context. That's the reason why I am in the dark as to what to do...

Comment: So you just came up with this equation out of the blue? The only hints that come up to my mind now are as follows: firstly, consider the special cases in which some of $a,b,c,d$ vanish. Then your equation simplifies somewhat, so maybe you will be able to extract some partial information. Secondly, you may write down a general ansatz $f(x,y,z) = \sum_{k,l,m=0}^{\infty} c_{k,l,m} (x \cdot y)^k (x \cdot z)^l (y \cdot z)^m$ and plug into the equation (also expand exponentials). You should be able to write down explicitly equations that have to be obeyed by $c_{k,l,m}$ at least for small $k,l,m$.

Comment: Thanks, that actually worked. I was already trying to find some general expansion, but that was too messy to solve. Putting some of the vectors to zero actually yielded some symmetries in the arguments that made it possible to find a solution. Thanks!

Comment: In order to not leave behind questions with no answers, please consider posting your own answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have, however, found out that my solution is not the only one. But this is what I found: $f(a,b,c)=e^{a\cdot b-a\cdot c-b\cdot c}$.